# How to generate an array of controller actions in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 4 app I have a number of static `pages` that should either be indexable by Google or not. I am using a variable `indexable` for this but there's probably a better way:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    indexable = true
  end

  def about_us
    indexable = true
  end

  def secret_stuff
    indexable = false
  end

end
```

How can I generate an array of all the pages that are `indexable`?

I tried doing this in a helper but it's not working:

```
def indexable_pages
  array = []
  PagesController.instance_methods(false).each do |action|
    if action.indexable == true # this won't work of course
      array << action
    end
  end
  array
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is probably the wrong way to go about doing it. Many of these actions cannot be reached by `GET`. What about something akin to what `rake routes` does? It's not the action that's indexable, it's the path that ends up at that action, of which there could be many.

Comment: @tadman: OK, agreed. But how can I get those paths into an array?

Comment: @anthony has the beginning of a solution here. You might want to extend the routing system to allow for flags like `indexable: true` to be supported.

Comment: @tadman: OK, sounds good but I can't find anything on Rails' `routes` and "flags". Can you point me to an example?

Comment: You'd have to really wreck around in the Rails routing system, patching it to include options it normally doesn't have. This is probably massively over-complicating what should be a simple problem, though. A simple way is to use a particular style of comment in your `routes.rb` file you can find and process with a utility script, converting them into your map.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a before_filter would make sense?

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_indexable, except: [:secret_stuff]

  def home
  end

  def about_us
  end

  def secret_stuff
  end

  private 

  def set_indexable
    @indexable = true
  end

end
```

Comment: You'll have to trigger each action to discover if it's indexable, though. This is of dubious utility.